# Removing @Inputs() from a directive like ngForOf

Tags: angular, angular5, directive, angular6

for my application I need a directive that repeats the template for each object in an array (like ngForOf) and detect changes. Therefore, I copied the source code of ngForOf and added:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.dataService.data.subscribe((data) => {
this.myDirectiveForOf = data;
})
```

I want to use my directive like this:

```
<hello *myDirectiveFor name="{{ name }}"></hello>
```

Because i don't the directive gets his data via the DOM and should not inject any variables (like item in the example below). Using the directive like :

```
<hello *myDirectiveFor="let item of []" name="{{ name }}"></hello>
```

is working fine.

How can I make the first usage of my directive work?

Here is a demo app :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-am36m1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: You should bind inputs with the `[]` syntax.

Comment: what is `=&gt;`?? is it same as `=>`?

Comment: I dont need and want any Inputs, beacuse i get my iterable object from a Behaviour Subject from DOM. 

=&gt; was an error in copy/pasting. Edited